# Cannot find rosserial_python serial_node.py

Tags: ros-melodic, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed rosserial_python using the following commands:
$ sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-rosserial-arduino
$ sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-rosserial

Sourced the setup.bash file.  And I get the following error:

rosrun rosserial_python serial_node
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named serial_node below /opt/ros/melodic/share/rosserial_python

The serial_node.py is not in the share directory.  Why is ROS looking in that directory?  I found it under /opt/ros/melodic/lib/rosserial_python

Does the lib directory need to get added to ROS_PACKAGE_PATH?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/361047/cannot-find-rosserial_python-serial_node.py/) by [mjwhite](https://answers.ros.org/users/39136/mjwhite/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2020-09-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I found the solution:

So I originally had installed rosserial_python from source in my catkin_ws.  I then removed that code from the src directory and rebuilt it with catkin_make ,but I still had the code in the devel, build, and install directories.  After removing the lib, share, and install directories from those directories and rebuilding then I no longer get this error.

Looks like the catkin workspace overlay was getting in the way of the code in /opt/ros/melodic.

---

Originally posted by [mjwhite](https://answers.ros.org/users/39136/mjwhite/) with karma: 91 on 2020-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [catmanjan](https://answers.ros.org/users/102936/catmanjan/) on 2022-04-27**:
This worked for me too